# Sending an email from PHP it shows headers: Mailed by: My.hostname.com

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hello guys I am triying to send an email from PHP in HTML format, the email its sending correct but arrive with this headers:
[Email from PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atfTY.png)

If I send an email from Wordpress, the email shows good:
[Email from wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkxal.png)

What I need to do to send my email as wordpress do?
Here my code:

```
<?php
$name    = $_POST["name"];
$email   = $_POST["email"];
$phone   = $_POST["phone"];
$product = $_POST["product_name"];
$country = $_POST["country"];




$template_File = "template.php";

$email_to = $email;
$subject ="asunto hoy";



$headers = "From: Roberto <fa.luis@outlook.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";



if(file_exists($template_File))

    $message = file_get_contents($template_File);
       else
die("unable to locate template file");


          $message = str_replace("#name#",   $name,    $message);
          $message = str_replace("#product#",$product, $message);
          $message = str_replace("#email#",  $email,   $message);
          $message = str_replace("#phone#",  $phone,   $message);

          if (mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers,))
            echo "listo";
            else
            echo "no listo";

echo $country;          
echo $message;
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: Try not to rely on images when posting questions, can you include the text instead?